# Applying a custom javascript function to an iframe element

Tags: select, jquery-plugins, iframe, javascript

I'm trying to figure out how to apply a custom javascript function to a dropdown menu element that is located in the iframe. Javascript changes the look and feel of the dropdown and works great for the parent page. It doesn't work for an element in the iframe. I searched this website for an answer but unfortunately some of the examples given here didn't work for my page. A couple of things to keep in mind:

1. Both pages are in the domain
2. I can't directly place the js on the page that is loaded in the iframe(code below is just an example, the real thing is not accessible to me)
3. I'm using the js libraries found here(i modified it a bit to fit my needs) http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown

Here's the page that will be loaded in iframe. I'm trying to style the select element:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Iframe</title>
</head>
<body>
  <label for="specialty">Specialty: </label>
  <select name="specialty" id="specialty" class="dropdown">
     <option value="calendar">Calendar</option>
     <option value="shopping_cart">Shopping Cart</option>
  </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the parent from which I try to invoke the js:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Parent Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.dd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) { 
   try {
      $("body select").msDropDown();
   } 
   catch(e) {
       alert(e.message);
   }
});
$('#frame').load( function(){
   try {
      $(this.contentDocument).find('select').msDropDown();
   }
   catch(e) {
      alert(e.message);
   }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <label for="specialty">Specialty: </label>
   <select name="specialty" id="specialty" class="dropdown">
      <option value="calendar">Calendar</option>
      <option value="shopping_cart">Shopping Cart</option>
    </select>
    <iframe src="add.html" id="frame" name="frame"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this doesn't seem possible.  It may be an issue with the plugin itself, in that even executing the function on the DOM of the iframe, the function instead executes on the DOM of the parent.